# Why does this query return different values?

Tags: php, database, mysqli, extract

I'm trying to pull information from my database, but the query I'm using is only pulling all of the values after the first one. I have no `LIMIT` set, but I did try setting a `LIMIT 0,30` with no change. In phpMyAdmin, the query returns what I expect. In my PHP file, it returns what I've explained.

The query is :

```
SELECT * FROM `mainSite_others` WHERE forGame='$gameName'
```

`gameName` is previously provided, and I suspect no errors because it does return at least two values. The forGame value in the database is all the same, a constant `"+Stellar+Dawn"`.

The PHP code is:

```
while ($gameOther = $database->fetchArray($gameOtherQry)) { 
    echo $gameOther['otherName'];
}
```

Don't worry about the `$database->fetchArray` part, that is just my DB class, which works fine as far as I know.

The table I am extracting from looks like this (this is with all the values contained):

```
id    |    forGame    |   otherType    |   otherName    |    otherDesc
9     | +Stellar+Dawn | Character      | Car            | Car
10    | +Stellar+Dawn | Item           | Brugson Burson | a guy
11    | +Stellar+Dawn | Item           | Space Pie      | A pie from space
```

I am using mySQLi.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: you're probably doing a fetch call BEFORE you reach that while loop, which "loses" the first row of the results.

Comment: @MarcB I am. Do I need to call that query only one time then?

Comment: Problem is inside a function You wrote to don't worry about ;] post a code of this function.

Comment: it's not the running of the query that's the problem. it's the fetches. once you fetch a row, it's "gone". you can try rewinding the result set, but that's not a good way to go.

Comment: @MarcB You're awesome, that worked. Also, can you post an answer so I can rep and accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably doing a fetch call BEFORE you reach the while loop, which "loses" the first row of the results.

Comment: Gotta run, will accept answer when I return. Thanks for your help!